# A Two Part Puzzle

Tags: word, rhyme

Part of me is injured, but there is no drop of blood.

The other part is mushy, but there is no sign of mud

This is my new address, because I belong here.

Place I came from, now no one lives there

You can’t tell what happened, after you are done with me.

This could happen again too, and that my friend is the key

What am I?

Hint

> 

Hint 2

> Part of me is injured, but there is no drop of blood.
>
> The other part is mushy, but there is no sign of mud
>
> This is my new address, because I belong here.
>
> Place I came from, now no one lives there
>
> You can’t tell my friend what happened, after you are done with me.
>
> This could happen again too, and that is the key

Comment: Is the current state of the hint intentional?

Comment: It is intentional @xyldke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your two parts are

> Cut & Paste

*Part of me is injured, but there is no drop of blood.*

> a Cut can be a type of injury but in this case there is no blood.

*The other part is mushy, but there is no sign of mud*

> Paste can be mushy, but there's no mud in computers

*This is my new address, because I belong here.*

> the result of the Paste

*Place I came from, now no one lives there*

> the result of the Cut

*You can’t tell what happened, after you are done with me.*

> the two operations leave no trace of how things were before

*This could happen again too, and that my friend is the key*

> You can always Cut and Paste again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> 301 Redirect?

Part of me is injured, but there is no drop of blood.

> The original location is no longer active. Computers don't tend to bleed

The other part is mushy, but there is no sign of mud

> The new location can be anything, but is usually clean.

This is my new address, because I belong here.

> A redirect indicates a new address for a website

Place I came from, now no one lives there

> The orignal address is no longer in use

You can’t tell what happened, after you are done with me.

> Many web clients will store the new address, so any attempt to visit the old address again will silently navigate to the new address.

This could happen again too, and that my friend is the key

> A redirect can lead to an address that's been redirected again.